# new record not visible in activity previews in mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I have a mapping data flow with an Azure sql database source.
For testing i have only 10 records in the source.

If i insert a new record to the database table, then view preview of the source data in the mapping data flow, and click the refresh icon, the new record is not visible.
I have to turn the debug cluster off and on again.

Sampling is disabled so it should be reading all the data.

Is there a reason ADF mapping data flow source might not be seeing a new record immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is ADF caches the preview data and the change in source data won't reflect in data-preview until and unless we change something in our dataflow which will trigger the actual computation again.

Comment: thanks, changing the name of the activity works. Seems quite crude. its a pity there is no option to avoid the cache, for use during development.

Comment: We got a lot of feedback on it and introduced an option to avoid the cache a while back.